# Why am I getting runtime error when I am trying to generate all prime numbers between m and n(m and n inclusive)?

Tags: c++

Why am I getting runtime error when I am trying to generate all prime numbers between m and n(m and n inclusive)?

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 typedef long long int ll;
 int main()
 {
ll n,m,i,ch,x,t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
cin>>m>>n;
int a[n+1];
//a[n+1]={1};
for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
{
    a[i]=1;
}
for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
{
    if(a[i]==1)
    {
    x=2;
    ch=0;
    while((x*i)<=n)
    {
        if(a[x*i]==1)
        {
            a[x*i]=0;
            ch++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    if(ch==0)
        break;
    }
}
for(i=m;i<=n;i++)
{
    if(a[i]==1&&i!=1)
        cout<<i<<"\n";
}
cout<<'\n';
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you are getting run time errors, it is good practice to add them as part of your question

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code and see where the problem arises. For which input do you get run time error?

Comment: @j.holetzeck ,actually this is the question on spoj  http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/     On submission I get runtime error. So, I cannot tell for which input I am getting runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as from the link in your comment we have the following constraint

```
m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000)
```

So your algorithm will most probably fail in line

```
int a[n+1];
```

for large numbers n:

array of n = 1000000000 (1e9!) ints (4 bytes) needs 3.7GB of RAM!

So your approach doesn't work well for large numbers as it consumes too much RAM!

(I can reproduce it on local computer, just add `cout` message before and after definition of the array)

**Edit**

To make this algorithm work you should reserve memory on heap (instead of stack) and minimize size by `int -> unsigned char` at least:

```
...
while(t--)
{
 cin>>m>>n;

 unsigned char *a = new unsigned char[n+1];
 ...
 delete[] a;
}
```

Comment: How does adding cout message make a difference?